# Flicker / no signal with three monitors on P5000

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm really struggling to get three monitors running on my PC. I'm using a Quadro P5000 which features four DP outputs. I connect three Barco F50 projectors to my PC via DP. For whatever reason, only two displays will work at a time. Anytime a third one is activated (by either plugging in or enabling / disabling in the nvidia-settings), the third one will only flicker and sometimes a second monitor (which worked perfectly fine before) will start to flicker as well. Sometimes all three displays work, but this scenario is not reproducible and I have no idea how and why this is affected.

The projectors are running at 2560x1600@120 Hz. I thought maybe the cables or the projectors themselves might be faulty, but this is not the case. Any leads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try at terminal"xrandr" the first line informs the current desktop size, if it is not correct, go-to settings/display and turn off every monitor not in use... Ubuntu sums every display into a big virtual display!

Can also try to merge them by turning on mirror.